# Did any government agency take Steve Rogers' blood after he came out of the ice?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agent-carter

In the ABC series *Agent Carter*, the U.S. Government took samples of Steve Roger's blood. However, as of the first season, they had used all their samples of it and the only one left was in possession of Howard Stark (referred to as "SR-53" by Howard). Agent Peggy Carter later dumps it into the Atlantic Ocean, and it seems all samples of Steve's blood are gone. However, Steve is later revealed to be alive and is under S.H.I.E.L.D.'s (or H.Y.D.R.A.'s) protection and watch for a while. **Did any government agency (S.H.I.E.L.D., H.Y.D.R.A., or otherwise) take samples of Stever Rogers' blood after he came out of the ice?**

Comment: Steve Rogers is 106 years old; it’s very likely his general practitioner routinely performs normal bloodwork on him.